# XA transaction not working using SQLJDBC driver with JBoss 4

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, xa

I am using `Jboss 4.0.4` and `SQL Server 2012` as my database. We have configured `XA datasource` using `jTDS driver` which is working fine. But when we are moving to use sqljdb driver as it supports `TLS1.2` protocol. But with this configuration the `JBoss` startup fails with following exception trace:

> XAException: tx=TransactionImpl:XidImpl[FormatId=257, GlobalId=xxx/3, BranchQual=, localId=3] errorCode=XAER_NOTA
>   javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The function COMMIT: failed. The status is: -4. Error: "*** SQLJDBC_XA DTC_ERROR Context: xa_commit, state=1, StatusCode:-4 (0xFFFFFFFC) ***"
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.DTC_XA_Interface(SQLServerXAResource.java:645)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.commit(SQLServerXAResource.java:808)
>       at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.commit(XAManagedConnection.java:147)
>       at org.jboss.tm.TransactionImpl$Resource.commit(TransactionImpl.java:2505)
>       at org.jboss.tm.TransactionImpl.commitResources(TransactionImpl.java:1847)
>       at org.jboss.tm.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:362)
>       at org.jboss.tm.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:240)
>       at org.jboss.mq.sm.jdbc.JDBCStateManager$JDBCSession.close(JDBCStateManager.java:613)
>       at org.jboss.mq.sm.jdbc.JDBCStateManager.initDB(JDBCStateManager.java:465)
>       at org.jboss.mq.sm.jdbc.JDBCStateManager.startService(JDBCStateManager.java:378)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.XSLSubDeployer.start(XSLSubDeployer.java:197)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1007)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:808)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:771)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1007)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:808)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:771)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:755)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
>       at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
>       at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:464)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the solution to this.
JBoss executes several mbeans as a startup configuration (configured in jboss-service.xml). There is an mbean 'JDBCStateManager' which tries to create the JMS tables on startup. There is an attribute of the mbean 'CREATE_TABLES_ON_STARTUP', I configured it as FALSE, which means no execution of sql scripts on every JBoss startup. This solved my issue and exception no longer exists.
Also please follow the steps to configure the XA transactions on SQL Server before running the application.